# Capture UDP packets in Python without loss

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp

I'm trying to capture a fast stream of UDP packets without missing any.

Packet size is known and fixed at 1472 bytes.
I'm generating UDP transmissions with another Python application and the first two bytes have a incremental counter so I can check if any have been lost on capture.

**Approach 1: read packet -> write to file**

Packets are being written to file one at a time as they come in.

Result: 100 to 200 packets lost out of 10,000 received

```
import socket
import capture_verify

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
address = ("192.168.252.147", 23850)
sock.bind(address)
previous_first_val = 0
out_file = open("out_bin.bin", "wb")
packet_count = 1E5
while(packet_count):
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(2048)
    out_file.write(data)
    packet_count -= 1
capture_verify.verify_file()
```

**Approach 2: read packets to memory buffer, write to file once 10K captured**

Packets are being stored to a pre-allocated buffer. Then written to file once 10K packets received.

Result: 7 to 15 packets lost out of 10,000 received

```
import socket
import constants as cs
import capture_verify

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
address = ("192.168.252.147", 23850)
sock.bind(address)

out_file = open("out_bin.bin", "wb")
packet_count = 1E5
bytes_to_read = int(cs.packet_size * packet_count)
in_buf = bytearray(bytes_to_read)
view = memoryview(in_buf)
while packet_count:

    # nbytes = sock.recv_into(view, bytes_to_read)
    sock.recvfrom_into(view, cs.packet_size)
    packet_count -= 1
    nbytes = cs.packet_size
    view = view[nbytes:]

out_file.write(in_buf)
capture_verify.verify_file()
```

Is there anything I can do to speed up the code and ensure no packet loss?

*UDP protocol is a requirement, can't throttle down transmission speed. Currently using Python 3.7 on Windows 7

Comment: If UDP is a requirement, then you will have to accept that there may be loss.  That's unavoidable.

Comment: The transmission is point to point. Data capture device to PC. If that helps any.

Comment: *"UDP protocol is a requirement, can't throttle down transmission speed"* - get yourself a faster system and make sure that your Python program is the only one running on it, i.e. no background jobs which might infer with receiving data. Maybe rewrite in a more optimizing language (Go, C, C++...). There is not much you can do to speed up your code. And UDP is simply not designed for this use case.

Comment: Thread off the file write?